# Не отображается картинка WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

Незнаю почему, но на телефоне не отображаются картинки из WebView выходит эта ошибка в логе   Validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY).
Я достаю картинки из приложения, а не из интернета.
(Но даже при работе с сайтами  выходит  эта ошибка, но не на чём не сказывается) А в моем приложении вместо картинки белое пятно. Пытался гуглить нашел еще около 10 похожих вопросов, но все были без ответа..
Так же я пытался использовать Advanced WebView но особого результата он не дал. 
Я так подумал, раз вопрос не популярен и на него нету ответа, может вы делаете как то по-другому?  Можете изменить мой код,если конечно знаете как..

```java
public class activity_stigmata_detail_4_view extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stigmata_detail_4_view);

    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);



    Intent intent = getIntent();
    //получаем строку и формируем имя ресурса
    String resName = "q" + intent.getIntExtra("mSpringMonthsArray", 0);
    Log.i("name", resName);
    Context context = getBaseContext(); //получаем контекст

    //читаем текстовый файл из ресурсов по имени
    String text = readRawTextFile(context, getResources().getIdentifier(resName,
            "raw", "..."));

           webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res");
}

//читаем текст из raw-ресурсов
private String readRawTextFile(Context context, int resId)
{
    InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resId);

    InputStreamReader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);
    String line;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        while (( line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
}
```

Картинку использовал в нескольких форматах
Исправил код на твой, но все html теги стали видны, в том числе и тег картинки. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> может вы делаете как то по-другому?

В общем случае да. Весь контент для отображения в `WebView` (html, css, js, images...) размещается в папке `assets` в нужной иерархии подпапок (если требуется).
Далее в коде нужная страница загружается по ссылке вида:

```
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/exemple.html");
```

**Всё!!!**

P.S. `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res")` - `WebView` посмотрел, ну ресурсы, а что брать-то оттуда - там много всего...
`"file:///android_res/raw/q" + intent.getIntExtra("mSpringMonthsArray", 0) + ".html"` - это как минимум. Но проблему с картинками это не решит, если они не прописаны абсолюто (например, `<img src="file:///android_res/drawable/image.png"`) или относительно папки `raw` (`src="../drawable/image.png"`).

Comment: Ввожу webView.loadUrl("file:///android_res"); (Я думаю от месторасположения файлов ничего не зависит) выходит не удалось открыть веб страницу

Comment: Может можно тебе где то написать?  Телеграм/дискорд/вк? Я бы объяснил все нормально, напишу еще про попытки решения, просто кажется, что тут я не смогу решить эту ошибку

Comment: А что мешает здесь в вопросе объяснить? Вы задаёте вопрос про картинку - а где она? В какой папке, как и где прописана, формат, разрешение. В идеале вопрос должен содержать достаточно информации что бы любой смог воспроизвести проблему у себя, а не гадать на кофейной гуще, как оно там у Вас получается - тогда можно рассчитывать на быстрый и полезный ответ.

Comment: Ну хорошо, я поправил вопрос. Какая я то ппроблема с html тегами

Comment: И как я должен был догадаться, что у тебя там не полноценный html, а просто кучка тэгов? Ну верни свой код, который работал: `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);`, с абсолютными адресами картинок он должен работать. Можно и с относительными если начало адреса указать первым параметром: `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_res/drawable/", text, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);` `<img src="image.png"/>`

Comment: Спасибо тебе огромное, странно, но все получилось, хотя как я помню, этот способ пробовал